# Using node js from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tail

I'm totally newbie on node.js so let me explain what I'm trying to do:

I want to install tail-http https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail-http and in this page it clearly says it is operated:

```
tail-http http://example.com/some-file.log
```

After install node and npm I cannot install it an use it as a new command, The far I get was:

```
$ npm init
$ npm install tail-http
$ cd node_modules
$ cd tail-http
$ node index.js http://example.com/some-file.log
```

That works, but is far from the simple usage expose on that web.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g tail-http`

will install it globally and you could use it anywhere then.

Answer (score 0):

Any package installed with -g (global flag) which tells the npm to install globally and available through out the file system. Make sure you logged in as root. Most of the times it throws a permission denied error. Or just use 
sudo npm install -g tail-http